# Get a first column range from a range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get a range of the first column from a larger range. For example:

If the range is `$E$9:$I$259`, the result should be `$E$9:$E259`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By using the columns collection of the range object like so:

```
Range("$E$9:$I$259").Columns(1)
```

Comment: But how to get multiple columns Range("$E$9:$E259").Columns(1:3) ?

Comment: You can't do neat and tidy things like 1:3 in VBA and I don't think you would have 3 columns in the range E9:E259. Either be more selective in your range selection and use all columns or loop through the columns collection.

Comment: with non contiguous range it fails. Had to sort an array created from range's adress, and then join it together first : `Dim TempA() , A as Range : TempA = Split(A, ",") : 
QuickSort (TempA) : 
Set A = A.Parent.Range(Join(TempA, ",")).Address : 
Set Col= A.columns(1)` .

Comment: Didn't you mean `Range("$E$9:$I$259").Columns(1)` ?