# Get the number of column range from a range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I link [Get a first column range from a range in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974367/get-a-first-column-range-from-a-range-in-excel-vba/53830639#53830639) to undestand the content.

My question is:

is it possible to know the number of the column if I know the name of the column? for example: I would like know if the column named "mycolumn" is the numer 1 or 2 or 3 or x... in the table named "mytable"

Regards

Comment: For a table you could find a match on the worksheet or within the table.

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with a named column in a named table. If it is really  a named column in a named table in your case, then [Structured References](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) may help: `c = .Range("mytable[mycolumn]").Column`.

Comment: For my case the right answer comes from user10798192. The only problem is that I don't know how to insert it inside my code.

Answer (score 1):

`Range("mycolumn").cells(1,1).column` will give you the number of the first column in a range called "mycolumn"

EDIT: My Bad - I didn't see this was a named column in a table - Axel's answer in comments is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>...  if the column named "mycolumn" is the numer 1 or 2 or 3 or x... in the table named "mytable".</sub>

To find the ordinal position of a column *within its parent table*, you need to look only at the range of the table, not te worksheet that the table resides on.

On the worksheet,

```
=MATCH("mycolumn", mytable[#Headers], 0)
```

In the following image, the above formula returns 3.

In VBA as a function,

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Debug.Print ColumnNdx("sheet2", "mytable", "mycolumn")

End Sub

Function ColumnNdx(wsnm as string, tblnm As String, colnm As String)

    Dim m As Variant, hdrrng As Range

    ColumnNdx = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    Set hdrrng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsnm ).ListObjects(tblnm).HeaderRowRange

    m = Application.Match(colnm, hdrrng, 0)

    If Not IsError(m) Then ColumnNdx = CLng(m)

End Function
```

The above function returns 3.

[image]