# Extract the first column number from an address in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract the **number** from the **first** column of a defined `range` in VBA. 
 Currently, my code looks like this:

```
Sub Column_Number()
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("$C$6:$I$6").Address
End Sub
```

The expected result in `Cell A1` should be `3` because `Column C` is the first column in the `Range("$C$6:$I$6")` and the third column in the entire sheet.

I tried to go with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974367/get-a-first-column-range-from-a-range-in-excel-vba/15974520) but could not make it work. 
Instead of the `column number` it returned the value in `Cell $C$6`.

How do I need to modify my VBA to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Column` property of `Range` object. Try below.

```
Sub Column_Number()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("$C$6:$I$6").Column
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way, you will have the column number and its letter, too:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
  Set sh = Sheet1
  Set rng = sh.Range("$C$6:$I$6")
  Debug.Print rng.column, Split(rng.Address, "$")(1)
```